# Client Side Web App Development

Tags: web, client-side

I am wanting to develop an app that is totally client side. But my main issue is that,

> IS DATABASE INTERACTION POSSIBLE ?

**So, the final answer is NO!**

Client-side scripting, is designed to manipulate and display the content, returned from the server.

Use of Client-Side scripts(eg; JavaScript) is to decrease the bandwidth usage, not to interact frequently with database.

Comment: I think you've greatly misunderstood what "totally client side" means.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying it to execute in browser but get data from database...

Comment: totally client side == no trips to server, ergo no db interaction.. unless you use something like localStorage/ WebSQL

Comment: Thank You Sathya, I was really trying a samething but my question representaion was really a mess :(

Comment: I was actually trying to add a functionality of storage. That was my real intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition if a site/app is totally client side (no server side code at all) then no, no interaction with a server (and therefore a database) is possible.

From what I can see, what you want is a site where all the interaction is client side (possibly a single screen with no refreshes?). If so, the answer is yes. You can write jQuery/javascript to fire off server side pages that take data from the client side and then interact with the database.

1. Pages can be written in HTML with CSS & javascript/jQuery [all client side]
2. The javascript/jQuery calls server side scripts/pages which interact with the DB [all server side]
3. The results from step 2 are returned to the javascript/jQuery and integrated into the page.

Does this make sense ?

Comment: I got it... So if I wan't a totally client side based, I can never interact database without server-side pages. Is it?

Comment: That's correct.
Put simply (so I can understand it!), client side is your desktop PC and sever side is a remote web server. Web servers run the database, your local machine (and your audiences local machines) don't.

Comment: Another thought. Consider what it is you're trying to save. If it's tiny (e.g. colour preference for the site) you could set a cookie on the clients machine to store this. If it's bigger (e.g. their name and address), go with the database option.

Comment: @Sathya was talking something about localStorage/WebSQL, could you tell me what was that

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage
It's HTML5 technology that stores data on the clients machine. Obviously it'll only work in modern browsers so, if that's not an issue, have look. If cross browser compatibility is an issue I'm afraid you'll have to wait for older versions of IE to die :-(

Comment: I got it... But why my post isn't voted up? Since I edited its content :(